# How to set maxDepthExceededBehavior in ehcache3 in springboot with programmed configuration?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ehcache, ehcache-3

I want to avoid  Max Object Graph Size reached for the object : 840 - error .
As per this

This element has the following attributes
maxDepth – Controls how many linked objects can be visited before the size-of engine takes any
action. This attribute is required.
maxDepthExceededBehavior – Specifies what happens when the max depth is exceeded while
sizing an object graph:

how can this be set in ehcache3 and springboot.Using programmatic config .
I am not using xml in springboot for ehcache 3.4

Answer (score 2):

The behavior was `ABORT` or `CONTINUE`. Right now, looking at the code, it does an abort. To get different behavior, you need a custom `SizeOfEngine` service.

Answer (score 1):

CacheConfigurationBuilder. withSizeOfMaxObjectSize(100000) helped to solve.

Documentation as below
public CacheConfigurationBuilder withSizeOfMaxObjectSize(long size,
                                                              MemoryUnit unit)
Adds or updates the DefaultSizeOfEngineConfiguration with the specified maximum mapping size to the configured builder.
SizeOfEngine is what enables the heap tier to be sized in MemoryUnit.
Parameters:
size - the maximum mapping size
unit - the memory unit
Returns:
a new builder with the added / updated configuration